# iOS 5 - Blank UIWebView causing long delay before ViewDidAppear

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xib, viewdidappear

Every time I try and add a UIWebView to my app, it locks the main thread for 5-10 seconds. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to prevent this.

- It locks between ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear
- The UIWebView is not loading anything. I have no Loading code
  whatsoever.
- This only occurs on my Actual Ipad 2 running 5.1. It does    not
  happen on the simulator.
- If I popViewController, and push it again, it doesnt delay

What I have tried:

- `[webView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];` in ViewDidLoad
- `[webView stopLoading];` in ViewDidLoad
- setting the WebView hidden in interface builder

Nothing I've tried prevents this.

I have a simple button that executes this:

```
TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:test animated:YES];
```

TestViewController is a blank ViewController with a UIWebView added to the xib file

```
@implementation TestViewController

  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
  {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
  }

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  }

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one? `[webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:@""];`

Comment: No Dice. Still hangs for 5-10 seconds, then throws an exception 
(baseURL requires an NSURL and you passed it a string). This shows that the delay is not in the WebView loading its contents, but in the drawing of the WebView itself?

Comment: That's annoying... how about `baseUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]`

Comment: Tried that. I put a log before and after that call, and it executes really quickly. It stops after that